# Showing a specific piecewise function is not Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I have the following problem.

Consider the function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined by

$$ f(x)= 
        \begin{cases} 
        x^3, & x \notin \mathbb{Q};\\
        0 , & x \in \mathbb{Q}. \\
        \end{cases} $$

Show that $f$ is not Riemann integrable on [0,1].

The way I went about it is as follows:

Let $P$ be an arbitrary partition of the interval $[0,1]$ given by

$$ x_{0}=0 < x_1 < ... <x_{n-1}<x_{n}=1. $$

Now since the Lower Riemann Sum with respect to a partition $P$ is defined as

$$L(f,P) := \sum_{i=1}^{n} \inf\{f(x); x \in [x_{i-1},x_i] \}(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$$
and in any one interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ there exists a rational number which would make $ \inf\{f(x); x \in [x_{i-1},x_i] \} \equiv 0 $.

Thus since $P$ was an arbitrary partition, we will have that the Lower Riemann Integral defined as

$$ \mathcal{L}( f) := \sup\{L(f,P); P \text{ is a partition of } [0,1]\}$$

will be  $$\mathcal{L}( f) \equiv 0. $$

We have similar definitions for the Upper Riemann Sums and Upper Riemann Integral respectively:

$$U(f,P) := \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sup\{f(x); x \in [x_{i-1},x_i] \}(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$$

$$\mathcal{U}( f) := \inf\{U(f,P); P \text{ is a partition of } [0,1]\} .$$

I would argue as follows. Since in all the intervals $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ there will always be an irrational number, say $l>0$ such that $\sup\{f(x); x \in [x_{i-1},x_i] \}>0$ and the distance $x_i-x_{i-1}>0$ then we must have that $U(f,P)>0$.

Thus since $P$ was artbitrary, $\mathcal{U}( f)>0$ so
$$\mathcal{U}( f) \neq \mathcal{L}(f). $$
Thus, $f$ is not integrable on $[0,1]$.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: Your argument is correct!

Comment: From $U(f,P)>0$ for all $P$, we can say $\mathcal{U}(f)\geq 0$ but how do you exclude the possibility that $\mathcal{U}(f)=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument seems right. You can even argue that

$$\mathcal{U}\left(f\right)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{3}{\rm d}x=\frac{1}{4}$$

Just a comment about terminology - to my knowledge $\mathcal{U}\left(f\right)$ and $\mathcal{L}\left(f\right)$ are known as **Darboux's integrals**. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral).